# chainsubstitution: which rule can detect the last character?

Tags: luatex, opentype, luaotfload

In the following MWE, I want to replace all `ſ` by `s` if they are at the last position of a line or document or some place where there is no next character.
I added two rules to show that it works for other places, but I can't think of a rule when the `ſ` is at the end. The rule having `after = {{ 0x0000 }},` was my guess, but it doesn't work.
[Here](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/fonts-mkiv.pdf) is a reference for chainsubstituion.

Compilation using `lualatex mwe.tex`

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua
{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "chainrounds",
        type = "chainsubstitution",
        lookups = {
            {
                type = "substitution",
                data = {
                    [0x017F] = "s",
                },
            },
        },
        data = {
            rules = {
                {
                    before = {{ "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z" }},
                    current = {{ 0x017F }},
                    after = {{ 0x017F }},
                    lookups = { 1 },
                },
                {
                    current = {{ 0x017F }},
                    after = {{ "b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "q", "r", "v", "w", "x", "z", 0x00DF, 0x0020 }},
                    lookups = { 1 },
                },
                {
                    current = {{ 0x017F }},
                    after = {{ 0x0000 }},
                    lookups = { 1 },
                },
            },
        },
    }

}

\begin{document}

    \setmainfont[
        RawFeature={+chainrounds},
    ]{XITS-Regular.otf}

    OK: gſſe eſg

    For the following I cannot find a rule:
    wanted is a \texttt{s} when a \texttt{ſ} is typed but the character is the last in the line/document: ſ

\end{document}
```

[image: luatex chainsubstitution]

Comment: get every line/word an reverse it?

Comment: I did such string replacements before using lua functions like `string.sub(content, 0, -2) .. "s"` but it operates on an earlier phase and conflicts at many points with the parser e.g. two line breaks made the compiler crash. At the font level this is not a problem, so I want to replace it by using such rules.

Comment: Actually I was suggesting this, nowhere near answering :D.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is probably easier to first substitute all ſ by s, and then re-substitute s by ſ again at those places where applicable.

Comment: Sorry, I just now really understood your point^^ (to workaround the impossible positions by inverting from the beginning) and it would work, but it's quite hard to fill up the other `ſ` that where correct before using patterns.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks, your approach works! Sorry, that I didn't got your point earlier.

Comment: You would maybe need to check that you don't re-replace s by ſ that weren't ſ in the first place ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht maybe you wanna lend a hand tweak/optimize his solution? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622681/247020

Answer (score 2):

## General answer

- From my tests, I assume that a general way to detect first and last character using such rules is not possible. In complex cases it requires multiple font features in a row, each one added in order like `RawFeature={+featurename1,+featurename2,+featurename3}` to get the wanted result, where each possible type is defined in the manual linked in the question and where the chained features can be of same or different type.
- A complex rule would be to check all expected neighbours of `ſ` like `eſ`, `iſ`, `oſ`, `sſ` and create a specfic rule that matches before the more general rule "match only `ſ`". The more general rule would then in praxis be the end of the string/start of string if the rules are good enough.
- Since I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, I let it open.

## Workaround for my use case

Thanks to the hint by Jasper (replacing first all the `ſ` by `s` so we then have the impossible positions already correct) I could make up a solution by combining

1. `substitution`
2. `chainsubstitution`

the order probably matters.

1. replace all `ſ` by `s` without limitations.
2. replace all `s` by `ſ` but with limitations (where it is possible)
3. now we still have too many `ſ` in the string so filter out some more with checking before, current and after.
4. filter out some more `ſ` by checking only current and after.

The current code needs some tweaking but the main problem is fixed.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
    {
        name = "subfirststep",
        type = "substitution",
        data =
        {
            [0x017F] = "s",
        },
    }

    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "chainrounds",
        type = "chainsubstitution",
        lookups = {
            {
                type = "substitution",
                data = {
                    [0x017F] = "s",
                },
            },
            {
                type = "substitution",
                data = {
                    ["s"] = 0x017F,
                },
            },
        },
        data = {
            rules = {
                {
                    current = {{ "s" }},
                    after = {{ "a", "c", "e", "i", "o", "p", "t", "u", "y", 0x00E4, 0x00F6, 0x00FC }},
                    lookups = { 2 },
                },
                {
                    before = {{ "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z" }},
                    current = {{ 0x017F }},
                    after = {{ 0x017F }},
                    lookups = { 1 },
                },
                {
                    current = {{ 0x017F }},
                    after = {{ "b", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "q", "r", "v", "w", "x", "z", 0x00DF, 0x0020 }},
                    lookups = { 1 },
                },

            },
        },
    }

}

\begin{document}

    \setmainfont[
        RawFeature={+subfirststep,+chainrounds},
    ]{XITS-Regular.otf}

    OK: gſſe eſg

    ſa

    ſ ſ

\end{document}
```

[image: replaced]